# mapping a multidimensional array into sub arrays based on a key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
  array:3 [▼
   0 => array:7 [▼
       "feed_key" => "URL"
       "table_key" => "feed_url"
       "table_name" => "data_feeds"
     ]
   1 => array:7 [▼
       "feed_key" => "network_id"
       "table_key" => "name"
       "table_name" => "networks"
    ]
   2 => array:7 [▼
      "feed_key" => "product_name"
      "table_key" => "product_description"
      "table_name" => "products"
   ]
]
```

this can contain lots of arrays with table_name(s) value repeated in any order.

What I want to do is group the arrays by table name and reformat to something like this:

```
    $data = [
        'products' => [
            'some_table_key' => 'some_field_key',
            'another_table_key' => 'another_field_key',
        ],
        'networks' => [
            'some_table_key' => 'some_field_key',
            'another_table_key' => 'another_field_key',
        ]
        // .. and so on
    ];
```

what is the cleanest approach using php7? avoiding a foreach if possible.

Comment: @MehdiBounya from the first multi-d array of arrays above each array contains feed_key, table_key, table_name so for array 0 in the first array of arrays it would be ````[data_feeds => [feed_url => url ]]````

Comment: I see now, can you post what have you tried so far so I can help you out?

Comment: first off I have sorted the arrays using usort and the spaceship operator to order the arrays by table_name then I set a variable called table to the first table_name -> value and create a new array using that value then if then append the table_key(s) => feed_key(s) to that array within a foreach and do a check to see if table_name = table_name if it changes I push to a containing array and start a new array with a key of the new table_name value but I want to avoid the foreach and use something like array_map

Comment: You should've posted the code you wrote **in your question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple and can be done with `foreach` (I'm not sure why you are avoiding it)

```
$result = [];

foreach($original_data as &$data){
    $result[$data['table_name']] = [
        $data['table_key'] => $data['feed_key']
    ];
}
```

This will give you:

```
array (size=3)
  'data_feeds' => 
    array (size=1)
      'feed_url' => string 'URL' (length=3)
  'networks' => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'network_id' (length=10)
  'products' => 
    array (size=1)
      'product_description' => string 'product_name' (length=12)
```

Comment: yep thats pretty much what I have:  ````$data = [];
  foreach($feed_map as $map)
  {
   $data[$map['table_name']][$map['table_key']] = $map['feed_key'];
  }```` but that isn't my question

Comment: What is your question? can you explain more by updating your question.

Comment: what is the cleanest approach using php7? avoiding a foreach if possible.

Comment: This is the cleanest way I can think of, and I don't see a possible approach other than foreach, is there any specific reason you are avoiding a foreach?

Comment: I am in agreement with you I was hoping I could use something a little cleaning, but cannot see any other approach either, main reason is its a really big data set and foreach + loading another large array in memory, I guess I can break it up into separate smaller arrays and this is my only option thanks for your help